# Insert a table using contents in page and more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get the content from a list and transform it to a table, insert some content which I will write and align this table

I can align easily and already have the list however I was not able to turn it to a table

This is the list

```
<ul>
<li>Success</li>
<li>SuccessWithRemarks</li>
<li>InvalidInputData</li>
<li>UnavailableData</li>
<li>EntityNotFound</li>
<li>InvalidParameters</li>
<li>ParametersNotSupported</li>
<li>RemoteSystemUnavailable</li>
<li>Timeout</li>
<li>AttemptsLimitReached</li>
<li>RemoteSystemError</li>
<li>AsyncExecutionInProgress</li>
<li>InsufficientBalance</li>
<li>SimultaneousTransactionsLimitReached</li>
<li>TransactionUnavailable</li>
<li>AccessDenied</li>
<li>TransactionCancelled</li>
<li>InternalError</li>
</ul>
```

Just turn it into a table with more 2 or 3 rows

Comment: Try posting the code that you have tried [mcve]

Comment: Please post your attempts.

Comment: Can you give and example of how the table should be rendered?

Answer (score 1):

Implement a function which takes the `li` tags and converts the stuff into a table

```
function turnIntoTable(input, rowCount) {
    var output = "<table><tbody>";
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) rows.push([]);
    var index = 0;
    for (var item of input) {
        rows[index % rowCount].push("<td>" + item.innerText + "</td>");
        index = (index + 1) % rowCount;
    }
    for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows.length; rowIndex++) {
        if ((rowIndex > 0) && (rows[rowIndex].length < rows[rowIndex - 1].length)) rows[rowIndex].push("<td></td>");
        output += "<tr>" + rows[rowIndex].join("") + "</tr>";
    }
    output += "</tbody></table>";
    return output;
}
```

and call it:

```
targetTag.innerHTML = turnIntoTable(document.querySelectorAll("li"), 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data would go in between the `td` tags.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know that but I can't edit it like that, I must use javascript to change this

Comment: Check my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

This javascript should create a table object in JavaScript.

```js
const lis = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].children
const table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]

for(let i = 0; i < lis.length; i = i + 2){
    const td = document.createElement("td")
    td.innerHTML = lis[i].textContent

    const td2 = document.createElement("td")
    td2.innerHTML = lis[i + 1].textContent

    //add a third td for a third column

    const tr = document.createElement("tr")

    tr.appendChild(td)
    tr.appendChild(td2)

    table.appendChild(tr)
}
```

CAUTION: It will only work as long as you have a `<table></table>` in your HTML